# What should a GraphQL resolver return when the query returns no results at all?

Tags: graphql

In regular REST I would return a 404 status. But as I see GraphQL doesn't use http status, how should I resolve this *the GraphQL way*?
Just make the query nullable and return `null`?
Throw some kind of *Not Found* exception?

```js
@Query(() => ContentModel)
content(@Arg('id', () => ID) id: number) {
    return ContentModel.findOne({ where: { id } });
}
```

*Not looking for a language or package-specific solution, just what would be standard for GraphQL*

Answer (score 1):

From the [spec](https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Data):

> If an error was encountered during the execution that prevented a valid response, the data entry in the response should be `null`.

Comment: And if there are no errors, just that the requested information can't be found or doesn't exist?